# How do I count the lines of a text file and delete the first one?

Tags: php

I have an html file that I use for my chat log. I am rather new to PHP I/O and I managed to make this (which works, but it isn't very helpful).

```
while(!feof($fp)){
    $line = fgets($fp);
    $lines++;
}
```

It counts the amount of lines in a file. I want to count the amount of lines and say that if there are more than 15 lines, then delete the first line so that there are never more than 15 lines.

Comment: You can't really delete lines.  You have to re-write the file without the first line.

Comment: for the count `$lines = count(file('file'));`

Comment: .. a db may be a good thing to consider

Comment: @Dagon I was thinking of that, but wouldn't it make the chat be slower and laggier?

Comment: A chat in plain text? Make sure you're using file locking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this:

```
$lines   = file('/path/to/file.html');
$last_15 = array_slice($lines, -15, 15);
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.html', $last_15);
```

Or one-liner:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.html', array_slice(file('/path/to/file.html'), -15, 15));
```

Comment: you win the internet!

Comment: I thought I heard some firecrackers go off somewhere. I didn't see any balloons though @Dagon

Answer (score -1):

[Simple html php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is a usefull library for manage DOM in html files, use like for delete
elements:

```
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');

$e = $html->find("#div1", 0);

$e->outertext = '';

$html->save('test.htm');
```